# How to make the regex to not accept only hat sign (^)

Tags: javascript, regex

I have tried `/^[^^]+$/`, it is not allowing `^`, but also not allowing some special characters like `<>(` that I want to allow.

Is there any regex that only not allow just one sign (`^`)?

Comment: Your problem description makes no sense. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: The premise of your question is wrong. `/^[^^]+$/.test('<>()')` returns `true`, because all of those characters match the provided pattern.

Comment: @melpomene It does make sense. For me it's clear what is he asking for. He wants a regex which will match everywithng except `^` sign.

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek Yes, but `[^^]` does that (match any character that isn't `^`).

Answer (score -1):

`/\^/g` will match all instances of the "hat" character.

`/[^^]/g` will match all characters that are not the "hat" character.

Using `+$` looks for one or more matching at the end of the string.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

https://regex101.com/